# Using System.Reactive in .NET 3.5 (in a shipping product)

Tags: c#, silverlight, licensing, reactive-programming

This question is no longer relevant now that microsoft have released a proper version of the Rx framework [on devlabs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx)

---

**Original Question**

I've downloaded the Silverlight 3 toolkit and [rebased System.Reactive.dll](http://evain.net/blog/articles/2009/07/30/rebasing-system-reactive-to-the-net-clr) to work on the .NET 3.5 CLR, and am really enjoying using it.

What I'd like to know is, can I ship it?

- The [codeplex site for the SL toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) states that the license for the toolkit is MS-PL
- I've poked around with it in reflector and found no additional license information

I'm thinking that I *may* be able to ship it under the MS-PL license, but at the same time it feels like I shouldn't, because I had to rebase the dll, and because I've still yet to see any official word from Microsoft about releasing the reactive framework.

The alternative is either to just do without `IObservable`'s until .NET 4.0, or write my own ripoff version of System.Reactive - I'd probably end up going with writing a ripoff version, even though this would waste some time.

Has anyone else thought about this issue, and is anyone else using/shipping the dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now the Rx is available directly for Framework 3.5 SP1, Along with downloads for .NET Framework 4.0 beta and for Silverlight 3.0

Download the version you need from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx

Answer (score 4):

MS-PL "grants you a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free copyright license to reproduce its contribution, **prepare derivative works of its contribution**, **and distribute** its contribution **or any derivative works that you create**" (emphasis added).  I'm not a lawyer, but that seems pretty explicit.

(This is subject to some other criteria laid out in part 3 of the licence but none of them seem to inhibit derivative works, they're more about reproducing copyright notices and not suing anybody when your Rx-based nuclear power station blows up.)

Comment: var f = Observable.FromEvent<FissionEventArgs>(reactor1, "Fission");